# How do I work around this installation error?

Tags: matlab

It's happening when I try to install Matlab:

```
$ ./install 
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
./install: 1: eval: /tmp/mathworks_21238/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: Permission denied
Finished
```

and even when I make sudo:

```
$ sudo ./install 
[sudo] password for dev: 
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
./install: 1: eval: /tmp/mathworks_22032/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: Permission denied
Finished
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the administrator permission--you need to be in the admin group. If you are in that group,you can add `sudo` at the head of you command to give ./install permission to install files on your system.

how about `sudo su`?change to the root